# Timeout - Google Compute Engine

Tags: timeout, google-compute-engine

I have some websites that is build on same a domain.

- Server configuration is 8 vCPUs, 30 GB memory.
- Centos 7.
- MySQL is also hosted on other server.

I did several tests by Jmeter with 4 computers. 200 users/computer, 800 users in total. The test link takes less than 3 seconds for loading.
The results are failed about 10% while CPU peaked less than 25% and SQL server's CPU is not more than 10% ever.

Other problem, sometimes I got the following problem while the server is not much connections.
Is there any problem from server or DNS setting I should check? Thank you.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFlym.png)

Comment: There are no details in your question about your tests, what the errors were, network configuration, locations, etc. The first item that comes to mind is a WAF detecting a DoS attack. Again, we can only guess.

Comment: Where are the Jmeter computers are located in terms of network topology? Could you please provide more details and evidences of the GCP or VPC performance issues?

Comment: Additional information request. 
any SSD devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
A) your error log
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.